# Copy data to temp sheet, skipping columns

Tags: excel, vba

The original code works. When amended to skip copying columns I get an error.

I would like to skip some columns when copying to the temp sheet for email.

Original code.

```
' header row
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New_IDs")
With wsBody.Range("A1:N1")
    .Value2 = ws.Range("B2:O2").Value2
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
iMailRow = 1
```

Amended code.

```
' header row
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New_IDs")
With wsBody.Range("A1:N1")
    .Value2 = ws.Range("B2:J2" And "N2:O2").Value2 
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
iMailRow = 1
```

Comment: @Luuk i still get an error and it is still copying all between columns values

Comment: My guess is your amended code has 2 ranges of cells so you probably have to do it twice i.e. `wsBody.Range("A1:I1").Value2 = ws.Range("B2:J2").Value2` then `wsBody.Range("J1:K1").Value2 = ws.Range("N2:O2").Value2`

Comment: Since your range is not contiguous, it comprises different `.Areas`; each area is a single, contiguous range (two, total, in your example using the syntax suggested by @luuk). The `.Value2`, then only returns values from the first area. You'd need to iterate the areas or repeat the process as @Raymond Wu suggests.

Comment: Hi Reymond and pdtcaskey your suggestion had worked however it works on title but now the actual data value it copies to; iMailRow = iMailRow + 1
                ws.Range("B" & i & ":O" & i).Copy wsBody.Range("A" & iMailRow)
                lines.Add i, CStr(i)

Comment: or how do i hide columns between two ranges before it is copied on to the email HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy each contiguous range separately

```vb
  imailrow = imailrow + 1
   ws.Range("B" & i & ":J" & i).Copy wsbody.Range("A" & imailrow)
   ws.Range("N" & i & ":O" & i).Copy wsbody.Range("J" & imailrow)
   Lines.Add i, CStr(i)
```

Comment: Hi It worked many thanks for CDP1802 and Reymond